# Remove page navigation 'back button' in google forms when using page breaks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Hi I'm making a Google Form using Google Apps Script. I am inserting page breaks between questions. Unfortunately this creates both a 'back' and a 'continue' button under the question - I do not want to allow users to go back to previous responses and change them, they should only be allowed to move forward ('continue') in the form. Thus I wish to remove the back button, or at least remove the user's ability to edit previous responses separated by a page break.

I have tried setting .setAllowResponseEdits(false) but this does not help.

I have also tried playing around with setting PageNavigationTypes but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item#setGoToPage%28PageNavigationType%29) is not clear and there doesn't appear to be a way to access the back button.

Here is my code for creating the from

```
// function to create form using previous responses
function createQuizTwo(uniqueID, previousResponses) {

  var newForm = FormApp.create(uniqueID + '_quizTwo');  // creates a new form for this user

  var newResponses = SpreadsheetApp.create(uniqueID + '_quizTwoResponses'); // creates a new spreadsheet to store responses for this user

  newForm.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, newResponses.getId()) // connect form to spreadsheet
     .setTitle('a title')
     .setDescription('a description')
     .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for taking part!')
     .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
     .setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false);

  for (var i=0; i<previousResponses.length;i++) {
    newForm.addTextItem().setTitle(String(previousResponses[i])).setRequired(true);
    var item = newForm.addScaleItem();
    item.setTitle('Please rate how confident you feel about this answer on a scale from 1-10.')
     .setBounds(1, 10);
    newForm.addPageBreakItem();
  }

  return newForm
};
```

Comment: If you cannot do it manually when creating the form, then you won't be able to do it in Apps Script. There's no extra functionality when creating Forms with Apps Script, the only gain is automation.